# Why I cannot declare varaible outside of Stored Procedure or Triggers in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I tried to declare variable in MySQL , but I noticed that I can only do it in begin...end.

I have tried with MSSQL and I can declare variable and use loops any where. 
Is this one of the advantage of TSQL in MSSQL over SQL in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. 
T-SQL is somewhat unique in this regard, allowing mixing of both declarative and imperative constructs in scripts, and not only in server compiled objects such as functions and stored procedures. 
Many other mainstream RDBMS don't support this as well.

If you are used to working with T-SQL, it takes some getting used to, but the bottom line is that it won't limit your ability to develop high quality applications on either RDBMS.

HTH

Comment: Thank you, So do you think it is better to use them in SPs, Triggers, Functions or Events? There is no other way?

Comment: I'm not saying what is better or worse, it's just a fact. 
I like the flexibility of T-SQL scripting when developing, but also a big believer in abstracting and encapsulating the database code from the application via stored procedures.